# RGB color in HTML and Photoshop

Tags: html, css, colors, rgb, photoshop

Im working on a simple landing page. I have 5 background version. So simple so flat. But here is my problem. I use eyedropper tool in Photoshop to finde what is the RGB code of the background. But its not the same. On my PC I can see the colors perfect but on other laptops or mobile phones its not great. I don't know what should I do. I saved the bg JPG, PNG but its still not working. Can you help me finde the solution ?

[image: on mobile and on my pc]

Comment: well the color also depends on the screen quality. Your querstion is not very clear. Have you any color numbers to explain the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the image for web in Photoshop.

cmd + alt + shift + s

Answer (score 0):

The color calibration differs from different devices. Every device has their own color scheme. However it will always differs. People will calibrate them according to their needs.